# Webview causing blackening of background images of various elements on page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-webview

The banner ads were working all good till today. I noticed there is flickering happening everytime the animation happens inside banner ad.

This is affecting the background regions of all elements inside Fragment/Activity wherever AdMob Fragment is imported and loading

```
class AdBFiller : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mAdView: AdView
    private val mAppUnitId: String = "ad-code"
    var fragContext: Context? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val adFrag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_filler, container, false)
        fragContext = context

        initializeBannerAd()

        viewAppender(fragContext!!, adFrag)

        loadBannerAd()
        return adFrag
    }

    private fun initializeBannerAd() {
        MobileAds.initialize(fragContext!!)
    }

    private fun loadBannerAd() {
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
    }

    fun viewAppender(contxt: Context, adFrag: View) {
        mAdView = AdView(contxt)
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)        // also same issue with SMART_BANNER
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(mAppUnitId)

        (adFrag as FrameLayout).addView(mAdView)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        mAdView.destroy()
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mAdView.destroy()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mAdView.resume()
    }


    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mAdView.pause()
    }

}
```

Layout (banner_filler) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".activities.AdBFiller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Call in place of usage is

```
 private fun inflateAds() {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .add(R.id.adStub, AdBFiller())
            .commit()
    }
```

adStub is a FrameLayout

I guess this is automatically happening because of AdMob code, as it was working good for many days.
How to insulate app, from the impact of these?

Although effect is minor in the video, **my other pages are greatly affected**

[[image: Video thumbnail]

Flickering video](https://youtu.be/YrTY3a3MmSM)

---

### **EDIT:**

Turns out this is an issue specific to my mobile/manufacturer and because of WebView loading on the page.
Since Ads use webview, it appeared as the cause of issue lied within the Ad injected code

Model: Honor Huawei - 9N,
LLD-AL20,
EMUI 9.1.0,
Android Verion 9

*Specifics:*

The content of webview has to finish loading for this problem to start. Some views are relatively unaffected. For every load of page, those same elements of the page are affected i.e. fixed reproduction means out of 50 elements on page, everytime those fixed 20 are affected.

I guess I have to position & inflate WebView is a manner which doesn't interfere with rest of elements.

Webview or ads are last element just before closing of the Root ConstrainLayout for the Fragment.

Has anyone found fix for issue like this?

Comment: Does it happen with every ad that is loaded or specific ad?

Comment: All banner ads, irrespective of content

Comment: your code looks good. I have seen it happening with certain ads ( high graphics ) and not with normal advertisement. Can you give a try with adaptive banners and see if that helps

Comment: I have shared your post in admob forum - https://support.google.com/admob/thread/95013131

Comment: Thanks Amod. I forgot about this most active community of google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

`android:layerType="software"`

Comment: I've got this happening with a Samsung Tab A on the latest webview version, but only for certain ads.  Changing the rendering type to software fixes the flickering but causes the ad to only show a black square.

Comment: @Tom Did you find any solution for your case? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @jmart Afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layerType="software"`

Just add it to the `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView/>`  and it will fix the blackening of background image when banner ads loads